# A series in the group of all numbers with divisors greater than $x$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have the following problem:

Let there be $x>0$ and a set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ s.t. all the divisors of the numbers in $A$ are greater than $x$.

Prove that there are $a,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ that define a series in $A$ of the form:
$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}. a+nd$

Not sure where to begin, any help will be appreciated

Comment: @DietrichBurde why is it trivial? I think it's infinite since it can hold all primes greater than $x$

Comment: Could it be that you mean "set" rather than "group", @Algosub? For example in Hebrew, both are denoted by the same word, or maybe it's just that the Hebrew translation of the word group (in the non-mathematical sense) is the same word as is used for "set" in the mathematical sense, as far I gathered.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer, the question was actually given to me in Hebrew originally. I'll fix the question and use the word "set" instead

Answer (score 1):

Numbers such as k*x!+1, where k is positive integer, satisfy the demands.